# How to change relative image URLs in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here after installing a wordpress theme I have this problem. published product images are not displayed. Therefore

I would like to display the image entered by the user at the sigle page of the publication. As on the demo version of the site.
Here is my installation: http://sekou.c-l-bon.com/listing/3-bed-apartment-67-sq-m-2/
Here is the demo link: https://finder.madrasthemes.com/real-estate/listing/3-bed-apartment-67-sq-m-2/